# Drag&Drop в PyGTK

Tags: python, gui, gtk, pygtk

Подскажите, как в pygtk реализовать Drag and Drop, например, чтобы получить адрес файла, перенесённого в окно программы. Находил разные примеры, но они были слишком сложными, не работали или работали не так: Drag&Drop был внутри программы, а файл перенести туда было нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Событие получения файла и передачи информации о нем находится на метке label2. Код формы загружается из файла example.glade

```
Import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf


class Handler:
    def onDeleteWindow(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

    def onButtonPressed(self, button):
        print("Hello World!")

    def on_drag_data_received(widget, drag_context, data, x, y, selection_data, info, time):
        print(selection_data.get_uris())  # результат - список путей до файлов в виде python list []


builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("example.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

label2 = builder.get_object("label2") # сигнал в файле glade на событие drag_data_received, функция on_drag_data_received
label2.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], Gdk.DragAction.COPY) # Получатель
label2.drag_dest_add_uri_targets()  # что передает, без источника работать отказывается

window = builder.get_object("window2")
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Сигнал на label2 (метка) - drag_data_received

Выполняется функция on_drag_data_received

Внутри нее переменная selection_data, у которой есть свойство get_uris()